# Firebase swift not retrieving all child values

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a piece of code inside my Swift built iOS app, to retrieve all the nodes from a Firebase Realtime database. When I execute the code below I've noticed that it does not return all the child nodes.

When I query the particular nodes which are not being returned individually, at first the code returns 'nil' and then on a second attempt retrieves the nodes. (without doing any code changes in the process). Following this process, the node starts to show up in the results with the retrieve all nodes function.

Example 1: First returns nil, then on a second attempt returns the node. Which I can see from the console and definitely exists on the database.

```
ref?.child("transactions").child(email).child("14526452327").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        print(value)
                        print("!!****************!!")
                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

The following is being used to retrieve all child values; at first this doesn't get all the nodes, however after running the code from Example 1 (twice) it starts to return the node in question.

```
ref?.child("transactions").child(email).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let childrenCount = snapshot.childrenCount
        var counter : Int = 0

        for trans in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        {
            counter = counter + 1

            self.ref?.child("transactions").child(email).child(trans.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot2) in
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the Firebase DB structure;]

I've also checked my Firebase query and data limits and I am nowhere near the threshold for the free account. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you describe you question more clearly by code? when you say `on a second attempt returns the node`, what do you mean ? you mean relaunch your app again and it print the node ?

Comment: Hi @JIEWANG, thanks for your reply. I simply re-run the app with the code provided above.. I do not make any changes...

Comment: check if your email variable has the correct value always,

Comment: Do you have offline persistance enabled?

Comment: This sounds like a simple debugging scenario: 1. as mentioned by shahzaib, your email is the only variable in creating your url path, print that out to make sure that's correct (for example if the email isn't set yet). 2. what does your console log say, firebase usually gives pretty good error messages. 3. similar to point 1, step through your code and make sure everything you intend to have initialized is complete before doing the "observesingleevent".

Comment: Theres also probably no reason your database reference should be an optional, I would look into that, since Database.database().reference() is of type "DatabaseReference".

Comment: Thanks, I’m going look into all of your points

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
func getData() {
    // Making a reference
    let transactionRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "transactions")
    transactionRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // Printing the child count
        print("There are \(snapshot.childrenCount) children found")    

        // Checking if the reference has some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            // Go through every child
            for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if let data = data.value as? [String: Any] {

                    // Retrieve the data per child


                    // Example
                    let name = data["name"] as? String
                    let age = data["age"] as? Int

                    // Print the values for each child or do whatever you want
                    print("Name: \(name)\nAge: \(age)")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer - Review